# multiple interface in java having same method name and variable name

Tags: java, oop, interface

There is an interface1 having method1, variable x and interface2 having method1, variable x.
Why does it shows up error in Line 1 and not in Line 2?

```
interface interface1{
    public int x =10;
    public void method1();
}
interface interface2{
    public int x =11;
    public void method1();
}

public class Test implements interface1, interface2{

    int y = x; // Line 1
    @Override
    public void method1() {  //Line 2
    }

}
```

Comment: Give the interfaces and methods sensible names and this problem will likely vanish.  Can you show a 'real world' example of this problem?

Answer (score 3):

'x' is ambiguous because there are two of them in scope, one from each interface. 'method1()' by contrast is not, because by the rules of Java the definition in Test satisfies the requirement to provide an implementation of it as defined in both interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface interface1{
  public static final int x =10;
  public void method1();
}

interface interface2{
  public static final int x =11;
  public void method1();
}

public class Test implements interface1, interface2{

  int y = interface1.x; // Line 1 or int y = interface2.x;
  @Override
    public void method1() {  //Line 2
  }

}
```

This is the correct way.

Comment: The compiler actually will implicitly change the types. The real answer is: Don't do that.

Comment: The only change here that is relevant is adding the 'interface' qualifier. Adding 'static final' accomplishes precisely nothing: it would be more to the point to remove 'public'.

Answer (score 0):

Because your assignment is ambiguous. You have to specify if you want `interface1.x` or `interface2.x`.

For example:

```
public class Test implements interface1, interface2{

  int y = interface1.x; // Line 1
  @Override
    public void method1() {  //Line 2
    }

}
```

Comment: Test.java:12: error: reference to x is ambiguous, both variable x in interface1 and variable x in interface2 match
  int y = x; // Line 1

Comment: @BrianRoach it's not completely incorrect. What are you talking about?

Comment: NM, I read the original post wrong; dyslexia kicking in. That said, this is still a horrible thing to do.

Answer (score -1):

in the final variables `interaface1.x`, `interface2.x`; if we take `x` of `interface1` the object referred might be different than the second interface.

But In `method1()` if we take any interface the body of method will be same, as `interface1.method1()`, is same as `interface2.mathod1()`.
But in the other hand with `x`.
`interface1.x` is not same as `interface2.x`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the values. Down vote. Your edit doesn't improve things.

Comment: The problem is that there are two x's in scope. It is as simple as that.